# how to integrate a lodash custom build into a project

Tags: npm, browserify, lodash, package.json

lodash supports [custom builds](https://lodash.com/custom-builds) with only a subset of the functionality / size. Creating a custom build is a breeze with `lodash-cli`.

What's the recommended way to take this custom build and integrate it into the project? (using npm / browserify).

Do I create a custom build command that creates the custom build and places it somewhere? (where?)

Is there a canonical way to specify the dependency and integrate into the project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several approaches you can take to use a subset of lodash:

- Use the CLI to generate a custom build (a file within your projects codebase) of the features you need
- Use npm modules or the lodash modules within your code base (i.e. instead of doing `_ = require('lodash'); _.each(...)` you would do `each = require('lodash/collections/each')`)
- Use the [`lodash-modularize`](https://github.com/megawac/lodash-modularize) tool to create and maintain a custom lodash build for a given project and use `lodash` as otherwise documented. This is essentially automating the two/three methods above.

Each approach is 100% valid and has their pros and cons

<sub>Disclaimer, I'm the author of `lodash-modularize`</sub>

Comment: Thanks! lodash-modularize looks totally awesome, but I was having a bit of trouble getting it to run (opened an issue on github). I didn't know about requiring individual methods, that's also very useful, but so far in terms of size - custom build left the smallest footprint. I'm very curious comparing to lodash-modularize.

Comment: Haha, thanks for the issue; made last minute changes without doing sufficient testing. I'd greatly appreciate comments/suggestions on the project, it's still a reasonably early stage project